# Issues Handling ChatGPT Streaming Response in Terminal using OpenAI API - Using Python, rich library

Tags: python, openai-api, rich, gpt-4

I am trying to integrate the **openAi API** model - `gpt-4` with Terminal to enable **ChatGPT**. My objective is to receive streaming responses from **ChatGPT** and print them in the Terminal.
Although I can successfully print the entire response without streaming, I'm facing issues with streaming responses. Specifically, the `ask_stream` function is printing every word on a new line, which is not the desired behavior. I'm using the rich library to handle Markups

My code:

```
import openai
from rich.markdown import Markdown
from rich.console import Console
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.auto_suggest import AutoSuggestFromHistory
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter
from prompt_toolkit.history import InMemoryHistory
import time
import argparse
import asyncio

openai.api_key = "MY API KEY"
model = "gpt-4"
delay_time = 0.01
max_response_length = 200
console = Console()


async def ask_stream(prompt):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model='gpt-4',
                                            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt}"}], max_tokens=8000,
                                            temperature=0.4, stream=True)
    answer = ''
    for event in response:
        if answer:
            console.print(Markdown(answer), end='')
        # sys.stdout.flush()
        event_text = event['choices'][0]['delta']
        answer = event_text.get('content', '')
        time.sleep(0.01)


async def ask(prompt) -> Markdown:
    if prompt:
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model=model,
                                                  messages=[{"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt}"}])
        if completion:
            if 'error' in completion:
                return completion['error']['message']
            return Markdown(completion.choices[0].message.content)
        else:
            raise Exception("")


def create_session() -> PromptSession:
    return PromptSession(history=InMemoryHistory())


async def get_input_async(
        session: PromptSession = None,
        completer: WordCompleter = None,
) -> str:
    """
    Multiline input function.
    """
    return await session.prompt_async(
        completer=completer,
        multiline=True,
        auto_suggest=AutoSuggestFromHistory(),
    )


async def main():
    print(f"Starting Chatgpt with model - {model}")
    session = create_session()
    while True:
        print("\nYou:")
        question = await get_input_async(session=session)
        print()
        print()
        if question == "!exit":
            break
        elif question == "!help":
            print(
                """
            !help - Show this help message
            !exit - Exit the program
            """,
            )
            continue
        print("ChatGPT:")
        if args.no_stream:
            console.print(await ask(prompt=question))
        else:
            await ask_stream(prompt=question)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--no-stream", action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`ask_stream` prints like below
[image]

Can someone suggest a solution to fix this issue? I am pretty new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part of your code:

```py
    answer = ''
    for event in response:
        if answer:
            console.print(Markdown(answer), end='')
        # sys.stdout.flush()
        event_text = event['choices'][0]['delta']
        answer = event_text.get('content', '')
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

To this one:

```py
    answer = []
    for event in response:
        # sys.stdout.flush()
        event_text = event['choices'][0]['delta']
        answer.append(event_text.get('content', ''))

        if answer:
            console.clear()
            console.print(Markdown(' '.join(answer)), end='')

        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: May be my question is not clear, I want to print the streaming data in Terminal as soon I received the event from API. I don't want to collect the response and print it which I already doing in 'ask' function.  Hope you understand my query.

Comment: I see, the problem is in Markdown, so, in this case, you should collect all available responses together and wrap them using Markdown again and again until you reach the end. The available option here is using Console's clear method. I updated the answer and you can check it.

Comment: Not working as expected. Its console.clear() clearing the console once its printed.

Comment: I think if you want to create a streaming output (like on the ChatGPT website) then you might want to look into the curses module.